# Haskell binary tree traversal

Tags: haskell, binary-tree, transformation, traversal

I am struggling with how to recursively traverse a binary tree in Haskell

It is rather clear how it's done when the return type is a list. But I don't get how is it done if the return type is a tree itself?

for example, if we have the tree and wish to exclude zeros:

```
                 5
                / \
               0   2
              / \
             0   1
```

and we would like to return a tree with the other numbers:

```
                 5
                / \
               1   2
```

Then I figured you would do something like this:

```
modTree :: Tree -> Tree
modTree Void = Void
modTree (Node l x r)
    | x == 0 = modTree l
    | otherwise = Node (modTree l) x (modTree r)
```

My issue is that I know that this will only traverse the left side. But I fail to grasp how recursively call the function in Haskell for the entire tree.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Suppose in your drawing, the root node `5` were `0`, and the current `0`s were `5`. What tree would you want to see come out of `modTree`?

Comment: You are not showing the exact tree structure. Are the leaves terminated with `Void` ? If so, it looks like you need to return `Void` for nodes with `0` value, and not the left subtree.

Comment: @EugeneSh. That will definitely not meet the criteria of "traverse both sides even when `x == 0`", which appears to be the premise of this question.

Comment: @DanielWagner Then I do not understand the description. OP, can you please post a sample input/output for a case where the `0` subtrees are not leaves?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Right. And now maybe you can see why I asked the question I did. ^_^

Comment: Then why are you trying to keep traversing down from there? Simply return `Void`.

Comment: @AwhatLoop Okay. Under the assumption that `0` only appears as leaves, your code looks fine to me. Can you provide an input/output pair where your current implementation does not meet your expectations?

Comment: @DanielWagner if the 5 and 0 switched place then the output would still be a tree with 5 4 1. The structure does not really matter :) I've also changed the example above to cover a case that fails.

Comment: In your update you a) Do not show the correct output, b) contradicting your comment about zeros being only leaves.

Comment: @AwhatLoop I asked my question (about swapping 5 and 0) very carefully. Please answer the question I asked, not a different question. In my question, the input tree has two `5` nodes: `0` at the root, left tree is (`4` at the root, `5` to the left, `1` to the right) and right tree is `5`.

Comment: Ohh i think i miss understood you when you meant that they are leafs. No the 0 can be anywhere in the tree, from root to leaf.

Comment: Supposing that you have a 0 node with 2 children which are not zero. What is supposed to happen then?

Comment: What will happen if the left subtree has two non-zero leaves? Like `1` and `3` instead of `1` and `0` ?

Comment: @PaulJohnson then you would return a tree with the two non-negative values. Which is root and which is leaf would not matter.

Comment: This "would not matter" matters. It needs to be defined for a complete implementation. These non-zero nodes might have their own subtrees too.

Comment: @EugeneSh. My thinking was that the left would take precedence over the right. I.e. the number on the left would become root and the right leaf. 
The reason being that when a zero is found I figured that it calls itself first on the left side and then on the right 
    | x == 0 = modTree l && modTree r  /// this code isn't correct

Comment: Then it won't be that simple. You want to replace the node with a processed left subtree, then you will want to *insert* a processed right subtree into that left one. That would be a separate operation.

Comment: Something like `| x == 0 = insert (modTree l) (modTree r)`

Comment: The insertion strategy might vary. For example traverse down to the leftmost leaf and insert there. Alternatively you might want to do it in a more balanced way

Comment: Would this be a good time to ask: why do you want to do this? I wonder if we have an X-Y problem here.

Answer (score 2):

One idea would be to bubble `0`s down and left until they have no left child, then replace them with their right child. For example:

```
    0          1          1          1
   / \        / \        / \        / \
  1   2  ->  0   2  ->  3   2  ->  3   2
 / \        / \        / \          \
3   4      3   4      0   4          4
```

You need to take some care about what happens when there are multiple `0`s on the path from root to leaf.

```
    0
   / \
  0   2
 / \
3   4
```

Probably the simplest (though perhaps not the most efficient) way to deal with this is to recursively drop `0`s from the left child before beginning to bubble down.

```
    0          0          0          3          3
   / \        / \        / \        / \        / \
  0   2  ->  3   2  ->  3   2  ->  0   2  ->  4   2
 / \        / \          \          \
3   4      0   4          4          4
```

I encourage you to take a stab at implementing this yourself. If you have trouble, describing what you tried, where you got stuck, and why you think the problem you're seeing is insurmountable would make a good follow-up question.

Comment: Challenge problem: what is the time complexity of this algorithm? It's obviously O(n^2); is it also O(n)? I've attempted to create a pathological input that achieves n^2 work in a couple different ways and they've all actually only required linear work -- but this may just mean I'm having a failure of imagination! I can't see how to prove that it's always linear. The trouble with achieving n^2 seems to be that you want to have a lot of `0`s for that, but if you have a lot of `0`s, then your recursive call makes a very small tree and bubbling doesn't take much work.

Comment: ...ah, got it. A left-spine-only tree with alternating `0`s and `1`s requires θ(n^2) work.

Comment: I like this approach, but I'm still having the issue of how to recursively go through the tree. In other languages, it would be: 
`postorder(Node)
{
   if (Node != null)
   {
       postorder(left_child)
       postorder(right_child)
       visit Node
   }
}`

But I don't get how this works in Haskell

Comment: @AwhatLoop In Haskell, you write `postorder Void = ...; postorder (Node left_child node right_child) = visit node (postorder left_child) (postorder right_child)`. Not so different, really, though "`postorder`" becomes a bit stranger of a name when the evaluation order is more fluid. (It was already strange because it didn't mention what `visit` was intended to do at all; now it's even stranger.)

Comment: Ohh I just grabbed a textbook example of postorder. "visit" was just a line to explain an action at the node.

Comment: I outline an algorithm in my answer which I think is linearithmic, at worst.

Answer (score 0):

The standard thing to do here is this:

1. if the root is non-zero we apply the algorithm recursively to each of its child branches and we're done (as you already indicate in your code)
2. if the root is zero with only one child we just return that child (transformed, of course)
3. if the root is zero with two child branches we apply the algorithm recursively to each of the two branches, then pull the rightmost value from the new left child and put it into the root.

To pull the rightmost value from a tree:

1. if it's a leaf, just remove the leaf
2. if it's a node, it doesn't have a right child, so just put its left child in its place

The whole thing is linear,<sup>(</sup>*<sup>)</sup> apparently.

```
modTree :: Tree -> Tree
modTree Void = Void
modTree (Node l x r)
    | x == 0 = modZero (modTree l)   (modTree r)
    | otherwise = Node (modTree l) x (modTree r)

modZero Void r = r
modZero l Void = l
modZero l r = let (v, nl) = pullRightmost l in
  Node nl v r
```

Implementing `pullRightmost` is left as an exercise.

---

<sup>(</sup>*<sup>)</sup>No spine is pulled from over more than once, because we are pulling from the tree which is already without any `0`s, "after" the recursive call. So these will be another *O(n)* operations in total.

Comment: Nice! This can even be made nicely lazy by hoisting each element of the right spine up one level, rather than hoisting the last element of the right spine up many levels.

Comment: yeah, I know they said the order doesn't matter but still it's nice to preserve it as much as possible, I thought... old habits, all that <s>cra</s>jazz. nice idea.

Comment: Ah, and the nicely lazy version also has a very nice proof of linear-time execution. Instead of thinking of hoisting, continue to think in terms of bubbling zeros down. The algorithm is equivalent to, for each zero, bubbling down left once, then down right until a leaf. No two zeros bubble down right across the same edge. There are a linear number of edges, so a linear number of right bubbles; and a linear number of zeros, so a linear number of left bubbles. Done!

Comment: so, to recap: because no spine is ever pulled from twice, it's all linear. both for my version and your refinement of it. (because the pulling happens over the result of the recursive call, which has no `0`s in it anymore). as to laziness, your "lazier" way might be lazier under preorder traversal of the resulting tree, but my way could actually be lazier under inorder traversal. I think.

Comment: Ah, good point about traversal order!